# Azure Synapse using ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication from PYODBC

Tags: python-3.x, azure, azure-synapse

I am trying to connect to Azure Synapse using ActiveDirectoryPassword authentication from PYODBC. I am able to connect successfully with my individual email address. If I try using any functional account with an email address tied, I encounter the following error.

> Error: ('FA004', "[FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18 for SQL
> Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user 'XXXXXXX@zzz.com'
> in Active Directory (Authentication option is
> 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').\r\nError code 0xCAA20003; state
> 10\r\nID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or
> authorized. (0) (SQLDriverConnect); [FA004] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 18
> for SQL Server][SQL Server]Failed to authenticate the user
> 'XXXXXXX@zzz.com' in Active Directory (Authentication option is
> 'ActiveDirectoryPassword').\r\nError code 0xCAA20003; state
> 10\r\nID3242: The security token could not be authenticated or
> authorized. (0)"

I am using the following connection string to connect.

```
cnxn = pyodbc.connect('DRIVER={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;ENCRYPT=yes;UID='+username+';PWD='+ PASS_WORD)
cursor = cnxn.cursor()
```

Answer (score 0):

To connect azure synapse using multiple azure AD accounts you need to create an azure AD group with your email address as owner and other functional emails as members.

- Go to Azure Active Directory >> Groups >> New Group >> create an azure AD group with your email address as owner and other functional emails as members.
  [image]
- Then add this group to your azure synapse >> Azure Active Directory.
  [image]

After this  try below code to connect.

```py
import pyodbc 

kpi_server_connection = pyodbc.connect('Driver={ODBC Driver 18 for SQL Server};Server=tcp:servername,1433;Database=databasename;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword;Uid=username;Pwd=password;Encrypt=yes;TrustServerCertificate=no;Connection Timeout=30;')
```

**Connected successfully:**

[image]